# Merge columns from many datasets into one

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have datasets for every month from Jan2022 to May2023 and I need to combine certain columns from each of the datasets into one. The columns I need from each data set are: rideable_type, started_at and member_casual. The tables look like this:

| rideable_type | started_at | member_casual |
| --- | --- | --- |
| electric | 2022-01-01 08:10:20 | member |
| electric | 2022-01-02 09:25:02 | casual |
| classic | 2022-01-03 11:32:13 | member |
| docked | 2022-01-07 13:15:26 | casual |

I am looking to create a dataset in bigquery, like the one above, that contains all the data from those columns from all the data sets (Jann2022-May2023) any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is only `UNION ALL` see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest_operator

Comment: Does below answer is helpful for you ?

Comment: It does help, but I was thinking that it would allow me to query the data aggregated into that table and I don't think I am able to. I was wanting to merge all the data together so that I could query the merged data and create visuals as well. I was thinking that making a table or something would allow me to do those things.

Comment: I think I figure it out actually. By using the code below, I had to export the information I needed, then create a new dataset and then upload the data into that dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I just used a spreadsheet to generate the table names, and then a formula to generate the SQL (with tiny manual edit to remove the last "union all")

```
select rideable_type, started_at, member_casual from Jan2022 union all
select rideable_type, started_at, member_casual from Feb2022 union all
select rideable_type, started_at, member_casual from Mar2022 union all
select rideable_type, started_at, member_casual from Apr2022 union all
select rideable_type, started_at, member_casual from May2022 union all
select rideable_type, started_at, member_casual from Jun2022 union all
select rideable_type, started_at, member_casual from Jul2022 union all
select rideable_type, started_at, member_casual from Aug2022 union all
select rideable_type, started_at, member_casual from Sep2022 union all
select rideable_type, started_at, member_casual from Oct2022 union all
select rideable_type, started_at, member_casual from Nov2022 union all
select rideable_type, started_at, member_casual from Dec2022 union all
select rideable_type, started_at, member_casual from Jan2023 union all
select rideable_type, started_at, member_casual from Feb2023 union all
select rideable_type, started_at, member_casual from Mar2023 union all
select rideable_type, started_at, member_casual from Apr2023 union all
select rideable_type, started_at, member_casual from May2023
```

There really isn't many alternatives to joining all those tables into one.

- Colum A Months
- Column B Year
- Column C ="select rideable_type, started_at, member_casual from "&A1&B1 & " union all"

Comment: Thank you! I am still new to SQL and your way is much simpler than the way I was thinking I had to do this.

Comment: No problem. If you are unfamiliar with **UNION** please note that if you do not include **ALL** that it will attempt to remove any duplicates from the result. This can be very useful, but it can also be wasted effort. For this question you need `union all` to ensure no rows are dropped.  ps: Are you aware of the "accepted answer" concept?https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: thank you so much for the help, I was not familiar with the UNION ALL. That makes it a lot easier than what I was trying to do.